# Subpixel antialiasing for arbitrary paths in Cairo

Tags: cairo, antialiasing, subpixel

Does Cairo support subpixel antialiasing on arbitrary paths?

I'm interested in subpixel antialiasing on text, but the version of Cairo that I am using is compiled without support for any underlying text rendering engine (such as Freetype). Therefore, I'm left with the [User Fonts](http://cairographics.org/manual/cairo-User-Fonts.html) backend, which seems to use Cairo's native path rendering APIs to render the glyph contours. Is it possible to achieve LCD subpixel filtering using this codepath?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Behdad Esfahbod says this is not possible. http://lists.cairographics.org/archives/cairo/2015-February/025982.html